# Plant/weed identification, Central Pennsylvania, had green-white bicolor leaves in April, now bright green

Tags: identification, weeds

Can you help me identify this plant in my yard in Central Pennsylvania? It started out with handsome green and white leaves, opposite, and fairly lobed/serrated. Stems were reddish-purple. Here is a picture from April 12, fitting that description, when the plants were already fairly large:
[image: Medium-large plant with bicolor green and white leaves and green and purple stems]

It looks pretty different now, a month later. The leaves are bright green, and the stalks are upright. The leaves are no longer bicolor and less lobed. Here is photo from today:
[image: Large plant with bright green leaves]

Here is a close-up of the leaves, also taken today:
[image: Five bright green leaves in a person's palm; leaf arrangement is opposite and leaves are serrated or lobed.]

I have tried to find it in the [New Jersey Weed Gallery from Rutgers](https://njaes.rutgers.edu/weeds/), [Minnesota Extension's Is this plant a weed?](https://apps.extension.umn.edu/garden/diagnose/weed/), [Wildflower Search](https://wildflowersearch.org). But then, I'm not sure if it's a weed, a native, or perhaps a vegetable (it's growing in an old vegetable garden).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an *Avens*, probably *White Avens* ([wiki here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geum_canadense) and a [good description here](http://www.illinoiswildflowers.info/savanna/plants/white_avens.htm)). It will be more easily identified when the flower emerges. Look at the last photo on my second link which resembles your first photo. Avens is widely distributed across N. America but hybridizes readily so this blurs the distinction between species and varieties. Note in particular the terminal leaflet which is sometimes so deeply cleft that it becomes almost but not quite three separate leaflets. Leaf margins evidently can be lobed varying to almost toothed or serrate.